# Why can't I place a C++ program in separate files to implement a Binary Search Tree

Tags: c++

I do not know much c++. What I am trying to do is create a Bst.h, Bst.cpp and main.cpp file. The program works correctly if all are placed in a single file. But once i place them in separate file, main.cpp starts giving errors like
..\Temp\ccK88Dum.o  main.cpp:(.text+0x22a): undefined reference to `Bst::insertNode(int)'
I am using Dev C++ to compile.

bst.h file:

```
#ifndef BLAH_H
#define BLAH_H
#pragma once


//Stores nodes of the tree
class Node
{
public:
    Node *parent, *left, *right;
    int key;
    Node();
};
class BinaryTree{
    protected:
    Node *root;
    public:
        BinaryTree();
};
class Bst :public BinaryTree{
private:
    // Pointer root will hold the location of the root node.
    //Traversal in preOrder
    void preOrder(Node *current);
    //Traversal in postOrder
    void postOrder(Node *current);
    //Traversal in pinOrder
    void inOrder(Node *current);
    //Search for the memory location of a node
    Node* findMeomoryLoc(Node* current, int value);
    //Finds a value is present
    bool search(Node* current, int value);
    //Display leaf Nodes
    int findLeafNodes(Node *current);
    int maxOfTree(Node* current);//can find maximum of a sumtree.
    int minOfTree(Node* current);//Can find minimum of a subtree.
    int countNodes(Node* current);//Can count noddes of a subtree.
    int countLeaves(Node* current);
    int internalNodes(Node* current);
    int findTreeHeight(Node *current);
    int branchOfHeightK(Node* current,int height,int maxHeight);
    int BranchHeightLessK(Node* current,int height,int maxHeight);

public:
    //Constructor initializes root to NULL
    Bst();
    //find successor of a node  
    int successor(int value);
    //finds successor
    int predecessor(int value);

    //Insertation of node
    void insertNode(int value);
    int deleteNode(int value);

    //Traversal methods
    void prOrder();

    void poOrder();

    void inOrder();
    //get Memory location of a Searched Node
    Node* getMemoryLocation(int value);
    //Search a value in tree
    bool find(int value);
    //Displays leaves
    int findleaves();
    //Counts Leaves
    int countAllLeaves();
    //Maxium of BST
    int maximumOfBST();
    //Minimum of BST
    int minimumOfBST();
    //Count Total No. of Nodes
    int countAllNodes();
    //Find Internal Nodes
    int allInternalNodes();
    //Get Height of a tree
    int treeHeight();
    int branchOfHeightK(int value);
    int branchHeightLessK(int value);   
};
#endif
```

My Bst.cpp:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "Bst.h"
using namespace std;
//Stores nodes of the tree
Node::Node()
    {
        parent = left = right = NULL;
    }
BinaryTree::BinaryTree()
        {
            root=NULL;
        }
Bst::Bst()
        {
            root = NULL;
        }

    void Bst::prOrder()
        {
            preOrder(root);
        }

    void Bst::poOrder()
        {
            postOrder(root);
        }

    void Bst::inOrder()
        {
            inOrder(root);
        }
    //get Memory location of a Searched Node
    Node* Bst::getMemoryLocation(int value)
    {
        return findMeomoryLoc(root, value);
    }
    //Search a value in tree
    bool Bst::find(int value)
        {
            return search(root, value);
        }
    //Displays leaves
    int Bst::findleaves()
        {
            return findLeafNodes(root);
        }
    //Counts Leaves
    int Bst::countAllLeaves()
        {
            return countLeaves(root);
        }
    //Maxium of BST
    int Bst::maximumOfBST()
        {
            return maxOfTree(root);
        }
    //Minimum of BST
    int Bst::minimumOfBST()
        {
            return minOfTree(root);
        }
    //Count Total No. of Nodes
    int Bst::countAllNodes()
        {
            return countNodes(root);
        }
    //Find Internal Nodes
    int Bst::allInternalNodes()
    {
        internalNodes(root);
    }
    //Get Height of a tree
    int Bst::treeHeight()
    {
        findTreeHeight(root);
    }
    int Bst::branchOfHeightK(int value)
    {
        return branchOfHeightK(root,0,value);
    }
    int Bst::branchHeightLessK(int value)
    {
        return Bst::BranchHeightLessK(root,0,value);
    }

int Bst::successor(int value)
    {
        Node* current=getMemoryLocation(value); //finds memory Location of the node
        if (current==NULL) //if the node doesnot exist
            return 0;
        if (current->key==maximumOfBST()) //if the node is maximum of the tree then it will have no successor
            return 0;       
        if (current->right!=NULL) //If the node has right child then 
            return minOfTree(current->right); //minimum to right is successor
        if(current->key<current->parent->key)//if node is a left child
            {
                return current->parent->key;//immediate parent is successor
            }
        else
            {
                while(current->key>current->parent->key)//loop to move towards parent until it is a right child.
                {
                    current=current->parent;
                }
                return current->parent->key;
            }

    }

int Bst::predecessor(int value)
{
        Node* current=getMemoryLocation(value); //finds memory Location of the node
        if (current==NULL) //if the node doesnot exist
            return 0;
        if (current->key==minimumOfBST()) //if the node is minimum of the tree then it will have no predicessor
            return 0;       
        if (current->left!=NULL) //If the node has left child then 
            return maxOfTree(current->right); //maximum to right is successor
        if(current->key>current->parent->key)//if the node is a right child
            {
                return current->parent->key;//immediate parent is successor
            }
        else
            {
                while(current->key<current->parent->key)//loop to move towards parent until it is a left child.
                {
                    current=current->parent;
                }
                return current->parent->key;
            }
}

//Internal Nodes
    int Bst::internalNodes(Node* current)
    {
        if(current==NULL)
            return 0;
        if(current->parent!=NULL&&(current->right!=NULL||current->left!=NULL))
            return 1;
        else
            return internalNodes(current->left)+internalNodes(current->right);
    }
//CountLeaves
    int Bst::countLeaves(Node* current)
    {
        if (current==NULL)
            return 0;
        if(current->left==NULL && current->right==NULL)         
        {

            return 1;
        }
        else
            return (countLeaves(current->left)+countLeaves(current->right));
    }
//No of branches of height k
    int Bst::branchOfHeightK(Node* current,int height,int maxHeight)
    {
        if (current==NULL)
            return 0;
        if(current->left==NULL && current->right==NULL&&height==maxHeight)          
        {

            return 1;
        }
        else
            return (branchOfHeightK(current->left,height+1,maxHeight)+branchOfHeightK(current->right,height+1,maxHeight));
    }
//Branches with height less than k
    int Bst::BranchHeightLessK(Node* current,int height,int maxHeight)
    {
        if (current==NULL)
            return 0;
        if(current->left==NULL && current->right==NULL&&height<maxHeight)           
        {           
            return 1;
        }
        else
            return (BranchHeightLessK(current->left,height+1,maxHeight)+BranchHeightLessK(current->right,height+1,maxHeight));

    }
//Height of a Tree
    int Bst::findTreeHeight(Node *current)
    {
        if(current==NULL)
            return -1;
        return 1+ max(findTreeHeight(current->right),findTreeHeight(current->left));
    }
//Count the number of nodes
    int Bst::countNodes(Node* current)
    {   if(current==NULL)
            return 0;
        else{
            return (countNodes(current->left)+countNodes(current->right)+1);
        }
    }
//Find node with maximum value.
    int Bst::maxOfTree(Node* current)
    {
        if (current!=NULL) //If root is not NuLL
        {

            while(current->right!=NULL)
            {
                current=current->right;
            }
            return current->key;
        }
    }

//Find minimum of a tree    
    int Bst::minOfTree(Node* current)
    {
        if (current!=NULL)
        {   
            while(current->left!=NULL)
            {
                current=current->left;
            }
            return current->key;
        }
    }
//Displays the leaves of the BST    
int Bst::findLeafNodes(Node *current) {
    if (current == NULL)
        return 0;
    if (current->left == NULL && current->right == NULL)
    {
        cout << current->key << ", ";
        return 0;
    }

    findLeafNodes(current->left);

    findLeafNodes(current->right);
}

void Bst::insertNode(int value)
{
//A new node pointed by temp is created which stores the value to be inserted.
    Node *temp = new Node();
    temp->key = value;

//We take a pointer current which points to the root of tree initially.
//parent is used to indicate the parent of current node.
    Node *current = root, *parent = NULL;

//If current is Null then there is no Bst and new node will form the root of the tree.
//If it is not null then it has child and current becomes the child.
    while (current != NULL)
    {
//Parent is assigned the current position and current goes to the child
        parent = current;
        if (value < current->key)
        {
            current = current->left;
        }
        else
        {
            current = current->right;
        }
    }
//Now we check if parent of current is NULL then currnt node is at root
    if (parent == NULL)
    {
        root = temp;//temp was used to store the insertion value. Now root points to it.
    }
    else if (value < parent->key)
    {
        parent->left = temp;
    }
    else
    {
        parent->right = temp;

    }
    temp->parent = parent;
}
int Bst:: deleteNode(int value)
{
/*  Node* x=NULL;
    Node* y=NULL;
    Node* node=getMemoryLocation(value);//gets the pointer to the node to be deleted
    if(node==NULL)//if number does not exist.
        return 0;
    if(node->left==NULL||node->right==NULL)
        y=node;
    else
    {
        y=getMemoryLocation(successor(x->key));
    }
    if (node->left!=NULL)
        x=y->left;
    else
        x=y->right;

    if(x!=NULL)
        x->parent=y->parent;
    if(y->parent==NULL)//if node to be deleted is root
        node=x;
    if(y=y->parent->left)
        y->parent->left=x;
    else
        y->parent->right=x;
    if(y!=node)
        node->key=y->key;
    delete y;*/
    Node *y=NULL;
    Node* node=getMemoryLocation(value);
    if (node == NULL) //if node does not exist
        return 0; 
  //if root has no child
    if (node->left == NULL && node->right == NULL)
    { 
        if(node->parent==NULL)//if it is the root node
        {
            root=NULL;
        }
        else//if not a root node
        {
            //parent should point to null
            if(node==node->parent->right)
                node->parent->right=NULL;
            else//if it is the left child
                node->parent->left=NULL;            
        }
        delete node;
        return 1;
    }
    //if node has 2 child
    if(node->left!=NULL&&node->right!=NULL)
    {
        y=getMemoryLocation(successor(node->key));
        node->key=y->key;

        if(y==y->parent->right) //replaced node's parent should point to null
                y->parent->right=NULL;
        else
            y->parent->left=NULL;
        delete y;//we delete the node that replaces the node to be deleted
        return 1;
    }
    //if node has 1 child
    if(node->left!=NULL)
    {
        y=node->left;
        y->parent=node->parent;
        node->parent->left=y;
    }
    else
    {
        y=node->right;
        y->parent=node->parent;
        node->parent->right=y;
    }
    delete node;
    return 1;

}

//find the memory location of a node
Node* Bst::findMeomoryLoc(Node* current,int value)
{
    if (current == NULL || value == current->key)
        return current;
    if (value < current->key)
        findMeomoryLoc(current->left, value);
    else
        findMeomoryLoc(current->right, value);
}
//find if a node exist
bool Bst::search(Node* current, int value)
{
    if(current == NULL)
        return false;
    while(current!=NULL)
    {
        if (current->key==value)
            return true;
        else
        {       
            if(value<current->key)
                current=current->left;
            else
                current=current->right;
        }
}
}

void Bst::preOrder(Node *current)
{
    if (current == NULL)
        return;

    cout << current->key << " ";

    preOrder(current->left);
    preOrder(current->right);
}
void Bst::postOrder(Node *current)
{
    if (current == NULL)
        return;

    postOrder(current->left);
    postOrder(current->right);
    cout << current->key << " ";
}

void Bst::inOrder(Node *current)
{
    if (current == NULL)
        return;
    inOrder(current->left);
    cout << current->key << " ";
    inOrder(current->right);
}
```

main.cpp

```
    #include<iostream>
using namespace std;
#include"Bst.h"

int main()
{
    Bst obj;
    int choice=-1;
    cout<<"\t\tWelcome to Binary Search Program"<<endl;
    int value;


    while(choice!=0)
    {
        cout<<"Select:"<<endl<<"\t1. to Insert a new Node.\t2. to delete a node\n\t3. to Traverse nodes\t4. Search a Node\n\t5. to find leaves of the tree\t6. to find Minimum value of the Tree";
        cout<<endl<<"\t7. to find Maximum value of the Tree\t8. to find total no of leaves\n\t9. to find no of Branches.\t10. to get the no of branches oh height k.\n\t11. to find branch with height less than k\t12. to find the longest branch.";
        cout<<endl<<"\t13. to find Successor of a node\t14. to find the predecessor of a node\n\t15. to find the number internal nodes."<<endl<<"\t0 to QUIT"<<endl;

            while(!(cin>>choice))//Validation of Number
            {
                cout<<"\n\tERROR!! Enter a number. (Symbols and letters not allowed.)\n";
                cin.clear();
                cin.ignore(123,'\n');
            }
        switch(choice)
        {
        case 0:
                cout<<"\n\t\tBye. See you again.\n";
                break;
        case 1:
                cout<<"Enter value of node to be inserted\n";
                while(!(cin>>value))//Validation of Number
                {
                    cout<<"\n\tERROR!! Enter a number. (Symbols and letters not allowed.)\n";
                    cin.clear();
                    cin.ignore(123,'\n');
                }
                obj.insertNode(value);
                break;
        case 2:
                cout<<"Enter value of node to be deeted\n";
                while(!(cin>>value))//Validation of Number
                {
                    cout<<"\n\tERROR!! Enter a number. (Symbols and letters not allowed.)\n";
                    cin.clear();
                    cin.ignore(123,'\n');
                }
                if(obj.deleteNode(value))
                {
                    cout<<"Successfully Deleted\n";
                }
                else
                    cout<<"NODE NOT FOUND"<<endl;
                break;
        case 3:
                cout<<"\n\tTraversals:\n"<<"Preorder\n";
                obj.prOrder();
                cout << endl << "Inorder" << endl;
                obj.inOrder();
                cout << endl << "Postorder" << endl;
                obj.poOrder();
                cout<<endl;
                break;
        case 4: 
                cout<<"Enter node to search\n";
                while(!(cin>>value))//Validation of Number
                {
                    cout<<"\n\tERROR!! Enter a number. (Symbols and letters not allowed.)\n";
                    cin.clear();
                    cin.ignore(123,'\n');
                }
                if(!obj.find(value))
                    cout<<"Node present\n";
                else
                    cout<<"Node not present\n";
                break;
        case 5:
                cout<<"\nThe leaves have the following values: ";
                obj.findleaves();
                break;
        case 6:
                cout<<"Minimum value in the tree: "<<obj.minimumOfBST();
                break;
        case 7:
                cout<<"Maximum value in the tree: "<<obj.maximumOfBST();
                break;
        case 8:
                cout<<"Total no of leaves: "<<obj.countAllLeaves();
                break;
        case 9: cout<<"Total no of branches: "<<obj.countAllLeaves();
                break;
        case 10: cout<<"Enter height of branch: "<<endl;
                while(!(cin>>value))//Validation of Number
                {
                    cout<<"\n\tERROR!! Enter a number. (Symbols and letters not allowed.)\n";
                    cin.clear();
                    cin.ignore(123,'\n');
                }
                cout<<"No of branches of height "<<value<<" is "<<obj.branchOfHeightK(value)<<endl;
                break;
        case 11:cout<<"Enter maximum allowed height of a branch.\n";
                while(!(cin>>value))//Validation of Number
                {
                    cout<<"\n\tERROR!! Enter a number. (Symbols and letters not allowed.)\n";
                    cin.clear();
                    cin.ignore(123,'\n');
                }
                cout<<"Total no of branches of height less than "<<value<<"is: "<<obj.branchHeightLessK(value)<<endl;
                break;
        case 12:cout<<"Longest branch of height k "<<"Not done\n";
                obj.treeHeight();
                break;
        case 13:cout<<"Enter value: ";
                while(!(cin>>value))//Validation of Number
                {
                    cout<<"\n\tERROR!! Enter a number. (Symbols and letters not allowed.)\n";
                    cin.clear();
                    cin.ignore(123,'\n');
                }
                cout<<obj.successor(value)<<endl;
                break;
        case 14:
            cout<<"Enter value: ";
                while(!(cin>>value))//Validation of Number
                {
                    cout<<"\n\tERROR!! Enter a number. (Symbols and letters not allowed.)\n";
                    cin.clear();
                    cin.ignore(123,'\n');
                }
                cout<<obj.predecessor(value)<<endl;
                break;
        case 15:
                cout<<"The No. of internal nodes is: "<<obj.allInternalNodes()<<endl;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please create a [mre]

Comment: probably is an IDE configuration problem

Comment: How are you compiling your code? Especially, how are you *linking* your code?

Comment: Please get rid of that godawful [`using namespace std;`](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice/).....